# Data structure for time-series analysis in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, xts, cross-correlation

It is a basic question but I tried searching and was not able to get an answer.

I have more than 10 thousand time-series records that relate to 420 different companies. For each company I have a timestamp (month/year) and a number of variables. Time-series are not of the same length.

At this stage all records are in one `dataframe` that looks like this

```
Date         Code   Var1    Var2    Var3    Var3
01/01/2010   AAA                
01/02/2010   AAA                
01/03/2010   AAA                
01/01/2010   BBB                
01/02/2010   BBB                
01/03/2010   BBB                
01/04/2010   BBB                
01/01/2010   CCC                
01/02/2010   CCC                
01/03/2010   CCC
```

I will later need to do cross-correlation, time-series clustering and build a Vector Autoregression model.

Question:

What are the guidelines to work with such data:
- use `dataframe` as it is
- covert it to individual time series for each company.

Happy to take any other suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no black and white answer: both object types have their strengths for different purposes (Although I would almost always use `data.table` instead of `data.frame` in asking your question, because you get far more capabilities.).  I personally use both interchangeably in research, but generally keep the original raw underlying data in `xts` format to begin with (tick or OHLC bar data in `xts` objects).

Both object types are fast, with computationally intensive code written in C.

If the dimensions (length or width) of your time series are not large, you can easily transfer back and forth (e.g. `data.table("index" = index(xtsobj), coredata(xtsobj)`) at the security level, and then merge `data.tables` if you wish to combine securities for cross-sectional types of modeling.  I typically switch back and forth between both object types for time series that I work with

`xts` objects must use all columns of the same type (`numeric` or `character` are the common types), which can be a limitation if you have categorical variables mixed with numerical data (you can map the categorical variables to numeric values to get around this, but that is extra work and can reduce clarity when modeling your data).

`xts` makes merging time series data (with `merge`), particularly at different time frequencies together, very straightforward to do.  It also works very nicely with building moving window technical indicators in `TTR` and `quantmod`.  You can also utilize `quantmod` (`chart_Series` and `add_TA`) and `xts`  plotting tools (see `?plot.xts`) to visualise out of the box candlestick/OHLC bar data.  `xts` makes aggregating tick data into OHLC bar data, and changing the frequency of bar data series (e.g. from 5 min bars to 1 hour bars, or to daily bars) very straightforward with useful functions like `to.period`, `period.apply` and `endpoints` (and it is fast doing it using C code).

If you are going to build prediction models (many linear regressions, or more complex models) with many categorical variables in your prediction models (e.g. sector of security, sentiment categories) that you do not want to map to numbers, it may be better to work with `data.table`.  Many prediction models in R (and unsupervised methods like clustering) require data to be in `data.frame` format, in which case storing/saving/loading your data in `data.table/data.frame` format might make more sense if your end goal is prediction modelling.  `VAR` models in the `var`/`urca` R packages also use `data.frame` format.  Although it is noted that many prediction models (via `caret` etc) require data to be in numeric `matrix` format, which you can easily extract from `xts` objects using `coredata(xtsobj)` (converting `data.frame` data to `matrix` format is typically straightforward too though).

If your data sets are really big (each security holds `n` GBs of price data in memory for large `n`), and you want to do repeated aggregations by groups (e.g. computed mean/sd of returns by month and symbol or month and sector, you'll probably find data.table more natural to work with), you'll probably find `data.table` more efficient it is designed to handle large amounts of data in memory/RAM and will tend to do less copying than `xts` operations.